# Shouldn't All Alternating Series Diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The ${n}$th-term test for divergence everywhere I've seen basically states that, if the limit of the ${n}$th term as ${n}$ approaches infinity is not 0 or doesn't exist, the series diverges. However, this test does not give any precondition on the ${n}$th term (e.g. that it has to be positive), so it should be applicable to alternating series as well. So,

> Shouldn't all alternating series diverge, since the limit of the *n*th term of the series, ${a_n =(-1)^nb_n}$ (including the ${(-1)^n}$), as *n* approaches infinity usually does not exist?

Won't this contradict those series that pass the Alternating Series Test (AST)? Or does the AST supersede the ${n}$th-term test in such cases (if so, why isn't this mentioned anywhere)?

Comment: What would make you think that the limit of $(-1)^nb_n$ does not exist?

Comment: The limit of $b_n$ must be $0$ for the alternating series test. From this it follows that $(-1)^nb_n$ has limit $0$.

Comment: @David I mistakenly thought that, since the limit of ${(-1)^n}$ doesn't exist, the limit of ${(-1)^nb_n}$ would also not exist. I checked Wolfram Alpha for the limits of ${a_n}$ for convergent alternating series, and they are indeed 0, so the *n*th-term test remains valid after all!

Comment: @Andre Could you please explain or refer a link to how you got this? In general, is this how limits of the form ${(-1)^xf(x)}$ as ${x}$ approaches infinity are evaluated?

Comment: Let's stick to integers, $(-1)^x$ gets us into trouble for non-integer $x$. If $b_n$ has a non-zero limit, then sure, $(-1)^n b_n$ does not have a limit. But if $b_n$ is after a while close to $0$, then so is $(-1)^nb_n$.

Comment: Two comments. First, of course it was clear what your error was, I was trying to get you to find it yourself. The problem was remembering things without the details: It's a Fact that _if_ the limits of $a_n$ and $b_n$ exist then the limit of $a_nb_n$ exists, and equals the product of the limits. But that Fact says nothing about limits not existing. Second: You checked Wolfram Alpha? That's very sad. Also dangerous - WA gets things wrong sometimes. If you think about the _definition_ of limits it's very easy to see that if $\lim b_n=0$ then $\lim (-1)^nb_n=0$.

Comment: @David Yes, it was a rhetorical question. Just wanted to clarify things for future readers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously there are convergent alternating series, so there must be some mistake here. We know that, for $\sum a_n$ to converge, then the condition

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$

is necessary (but not sufficient!). So if we take $a_n=(-1)^nb_n$, then if $\sum (-1)^nb_n$ converges, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^nb_n=0$$

which happens if and only if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$$

so well, we can have an alternating sequence who's series converges, but we *need* to have $b_n\to 0$ for $\sum (-1)^nb_n$ to converge. An example:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac1k=-\log(2)$$

on the other hand, we can make a series like
\begin{equation}
c_n=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
\frac{1}{2n} \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for which actually

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nc_n$$

actually *diverges* to $+\infty$, but $\lim c_n\to 0$. We again see, for $\sum (-1)^nb_n$ to converge, the condition $\lim b_n=0$ is necessary, but not sufficient.